# Is there any way to make the spiral's depth from circle shape to solid flat shape?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Basically I want to make it flat like the image shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from a mesh (the first image in your question), you can use a cast modifier, set it to cylinder and tune the factor value:

[image]

Comment: Awsome..  you are the dude.. ;-)